# Hiding variation info and product title in WooCommerce cart page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hide, cart, product-variations

Great Devs! I tried hiding the variation details and product title on the cart page, but the code seems not to work. Please can you help out? Thanks for the support

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_title_include_attributes', 'custom_product_variation_title', 10, 2 );
function custom_product_variation_title($should_include_attributes, $product){
    $should_include_attributes = false;
return $should_include_attributes;
}
```

To hide all of the items below on cart page

T-Shirt (Product Title)

Color: White (Variation 1)

Size: Medium (Variation 2)

Length:4l (Variation 3)

Answer (score 0):

These CSS code solved it.Thanks

```
    .woocommerce td.product-name dl.variation dt {
    display: none!important;
}

.woocommerce td.product-name dl.variation p, .woocommerce td.product-name     dl.variation:last-child {
display: none;
}
```